# How to create font encoding table to support chinese characters for zebra printer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii, zebra

I found out from zebra site that to print Chinese characters we need to load Dat file and load it is ^SE command. Below is the command.

```
^XA
^CW1,E:SIMSUN.TTF
^SEE:GB18030.DAT^CI26
^FO50,60^A1N,20,20^FD简体中文abcd1234^FS
^FO50,160^A1N,30,30^FD简体中文abcd1234^FS
^FO50,260^A1N,50,50^FD简体中文abcd1234^FS
^XZ
```

How to create GB18030.DAT file or can we get it from internet?